# Google Maps v3 - How to center using an address on initialize?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Using Google Maps API v3, is there a way to set the center of the map on initialize? I have a workaround using this code:

```
var geocoder;
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    codeAddress('germany');
  }

  function codeAddress(address) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

The only problem is that when it initializes, it centers it to the "latlng" for a split second. I'm can't figure out how to set the center in "myOptions".  I though I could return "results[0].geometry.location" from the codeAddress function and pass it to myOptions, but that doesn't work.

Thanks for any help.

**Update**
Since I can't remove "center" altogether, I'm wondering if there's a way to pass the address to the options.

> From Google API:
>
> To initialize a Map, we first create a Map options object to contain map initialization variables.
>   This object is not constructed; instead it is created as an object literal. There are two required
>   options for every map: *center* and *zoom*.

Comment: Another nice example using `geocoder` on Gist: https://gist.github.com/mahedi2014/a71e1bbcbd69d4a9d491b0f289894d2d

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Well a simple solution could be to initialize the map in your codeAddress function:

```
var geocoder, map;

function codeAddress(address) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: results[0].geometry.location,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        }
    });
}
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: I kept trying to include the geocode function in the initialize function... but it actually works the other way around. Thanks!

Comment: I know this is in the documents but what happened to initMap? Like do I abandon that now?

Answer (score 0):

This is an amazing answer that really helped me get super far. The only issue now is that `setCenter` is no longer valid in the JavaScript API. Here's my example using `fitBounds`, ES6 arrow functions to access a `this` reference to the google map angular component, and finally implementing `ngOnChanges` to listen for changes to an address text field and re-render the map accordingly.

```
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        const newFormattedAddress = changes['formattedAddress']?.currentValue;
        if (!newFormattedAddress) {
            return;
        }

        // if we received an update to the formattedAddress from the search box
        const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode(
            {
                address: newFormattedAddress
            },
            (results: GeocoderResult[], status: GeocoderStatus) => {
                if (status === GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length > 0) {
                    const firstResult = results[0].geometry;
                    const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                    if (firstResult.viewport) {
                        // Only geocodes have viewport.
                        bounds.union(firstResult.viewport);
                    } else {
                        bounds.extend(firstResult.location);
                    }

                    this.map.fitBounds(bounds);
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

External references and credit for the `fitBounds` code: https://kevinkreuzer.medium.com/how-to-implement-an-address-search-with-angular-and-google-maps-32a2df09f8e9

[image: kevinkreuzer.medium.com - Google Address Autocomplete feature using Angular]