# Google Map on Load Position

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Maps v3 - How to center using an address on initialize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140303/google-maps-v3-how-to-center-using-an-address-on-initialize)

I have a map that I would like to load with 90210 as the zip code...the alert is in there as a debug tool..the alert gives me the coords but I get 'myOptions is not defined' error.

```
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var lat = '';
    var lng = '';
    var address = '90210';
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            //alert(lat + ', ' + lng);
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        };

        var latlng = '(' + lat + ', ' + lng + ')';
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        alert(latlng);
    });

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate question somewhat.. It's answered here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140303/google-maps-v3-how-to-center-using-an-address-on-initialize/6140398#6140398][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140303/google-maps-v3-how-to-center-using-an-address-on-initialize/6140398#6140398

Comment: The "duplicate" is different. Shouldn't be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You create myOptions inside the anonymous function in geocoder.geocode.  So it's not available to the code outwith that function.  If you declare var myOptions in the top of your initialize function, then it should work:

```
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var lat = '';
    var lng = '';
    var address = '90210';
    var myOptions;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            //alert(lat + ', ' + lng);
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        };

        var latlng = '(' + lat + ', ' + lng + ')';
        myOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        alert(latlng);
    });

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
}
```